# Shell:How to substitute the field of the text while keeping the same blank space

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I want to substitute a certain filed of the text while keeping the same blank space:

For example, my text is:

```
Please              help         me     with this problem
Any                 suggestion   or     help will be appreciated
Thanks              to           all    who  give help
```

And I want to replace the sentence
"Any                 suggestion   or     help will be appreciated" 
with
"I                   want         the    solution"

So that the text will be:

```
Please              help         me     with this problem
I                   want         the    solution
Thanks              to           all    who  give help
```

I have a solution:

```
awk '{if($1=="Any" && $2=="suggestion" && $3=="or" && $4=="help"  {$1="I";$2="want";$3="the";$4="solution"};print $0}' eg.txt
```

I will get

```
Please              help         me     with this problem
I want the solution will be appreciated
Thanks              to           all    who  give help
```

As you can see, it has two problems

(1) the blank space is not the same with others.

(2) $5, $6,$7 "**will be appreciated**" of the former line are still kept.

I know another solution:

```
awk '{if($1=="Any" && $2=="suggestion" && $3=="or" && $4=="help"  print "I                   want         the    solution";print $0}' eg.txt
```

will solve the problem.
But I just wondering if there is better way?
Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: You'll need to know - or calculate - how wide each of the fields is, and then use a printf format code such as '%-15s' if the field is 15 characters wide.  You'll also have to ensure you zap all the old fields left over.  This commentary assumes awk is more appropriate than sed - actually, it would be very tough to do the job in sed; sufficiently tough that I wouldn't bother to try.

Comment: Jonathan,thanks for your comments. I always thought there maybe easier way to solve this problem. Maybe it isn't so simple as I had thought.

Comment: If you're using gawk and you know your field widths in advance, you can get a tiny head start using the `FIELDWIDTHS` feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example in `awk`. This code uses Jonathan's suggestion of `printf` with a width specifier. `match` is used to find the correct width.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    n1 = split("Any suggestion or help will be appreciated", a1)
    split("I want the solution", a2)
}
{
    j = k = 0
    if (NF != n1)
        k  = 1
    for (i = 1; k == 0 && i <= NF; i++)
        if ($i != a1[i])
            k = 1
    if (k) {
        print
        next
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        match(substr($0, j), /[^ ]+ */)
        printf "%-*s", RLENGTH, a2[i]
        j += RLENGTH
    }
    print ""
}
```

Comment: schot, many thanks for your detailed codes. It is of great help to me. It seems I must know the length of the blank space.